# Multiple providers Angular 2 test bed

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I can't seem to register multiple providers (services) in an angular 2 test bed. All I want is to provide more than one service to the testbed. Here is an example of what my current test suite looks like.

```
export function main() {

  describe('Create Applications Component test suite:', () => {

    let fixtureComponent:any, nativeComponentElement:any;

    beforeEach(() => {

      return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [CreateApplicationComponent]
      }).overrideComponent(CreateApplicationComponent, {
        set: {
          providers: [
            {
              provide: injector,
              useClass: MockCreateApplicationService
            }
          ]
        }
      })
      .compileComponents().then(() => {
        fixtureComponent =  TestBed.createComponent(CreateApplicationComponent);
        nativeComponentElement = fixtureComponent.nativeElement;
        return fixtureComponent;
      });
    });

    it('component should work without errors', () => {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

  });

}
```

What I need to get to will be something like this:

```
.overrideComponent(CreateApplicationComponent, {
    set: {
      providers: [
        {
          provide: injector,
          useClass: MockCreateApplicationService
        },
        {
          provide: providerB,
          useClass: SecondProvider
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```

Comment: `What I need to get to will be something like this:` what seems to be the problem with it?

Comment: When I added the second provider, I got an error saying `no provider for form builder` so I just added the form builder in as an additional provider, within the overrideComponent method, and everything works. Thank you for asking!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that is the correct way to add multiple providers. I was just confused by an error I received for missing formBuilder provider so I added that and now everything is working as expected.

solution:

```
.overrideComponent(CreateApplicationComponent, {
    set: {
      providers: [
        { provide: CreateApplicationService, useClass: MockCreateApplicationService },
        { provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService },
        { provide: FormBuilder, useClass: FormBuilder }
      ]
    }
  })
```